# How to iterate through the inputs to a function

Tags: python, pandas

How do I properly feed data into functions using pandas? The code below is currently resulting in the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

All I want to do is to create an output matrix with strings subject to the conditional statements in the function.

```
def mixtapeFire(timesPlayed, rating): 
    if timesPlayed >=1000 & rating >=3:
        print('Your mixtape is fire!')

    if rating >5:
        print('Invalid Input. Play Again.')
    else:
        print('You should quit the rap game.')

input1 = pd.DataFrame([900,2000,1001,500,4000])
input2 = pd.DataFrame([3,4,3,1,2])

for x in range(1,5):
    output = pd.DataFrame(mixtapeFire(input1.iloc[x,:],input2.iloc[x,:]))
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = pd.DataFrame([900,2000,1001,500,4000])
b = pd.DataFrame([3,4,3,1,2])
```

Making a comparison on a Series results in multiple values.

```
In [12]: a >= 1000
Out[12]: 
       0
0  False
1   True
2   True
3  False
4   True

In [13]: b >= 3
Out[13]: 
       0
0   True
1   True
2   True
3  False
4  False

In [14]: q = (a >= 1000) & (b >= 3)

In [15]: q
Out[15]: 
       0
0  False
1   True
2   True
3  False
4  False
```

Use `.any()` or `.all()` depending on what you want.

```
In [16]: q.any()
Out[16]: 
0    True
dtype: bool

In [17]: q.all()
Out[17]: 
0    False
dtype: bool
```

Because there are multiple `True/False` values in the result *it* cannot tell whether the whole Series is `True` or `False`.

```
In [18]: bool(q)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-6fd0a485fec6>", line 1, in <module>
    bool(q)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 955, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a perfectly working solution, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it and retain the function. For instance, if a function is a lot more complex, it may take ages to replicate it.

Comment: You can use the same process I showed in a function. You just need to apply your logic and comparison values to fit your needs. It wasn't clear from your question or your example what your specifications/desires were.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it's not very articulate now that I'm looking at it again. In short, I wanted to learn how to perform multi-class classification given a function-classifier [like a decision tree] and multiple inputs. The goal would be to produce an output array with string-labels, that would tell us what is what.

Comment: Maybe you should delete this question and ask one that properly reflects your problem/issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need you can apply any of the "a" methods to your arguments input1.iloc[x,:],input2.iloc[x,:]. For example:

`output = pd.DataFrame(mixtapeFire(input1.iloc[x,:].all(),input2.iloc[x,:].all()))`

You can read more about pandas access methods from official docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html

But in a nutshell: you need to be more specific which values you want to get parsed.